# Out of memory problems in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Well, I'm almost giving up to be a programmer and becoming a designer. Just kidding! So, I'm developing a app that is going to be used in field, without Internet. So that the user can access the information, first he has to import all the information before going to the field. The user can attend to many cities, he has to import the data of each city. Some of those cities has more than 4.000 of farmers registered. I searched trying to learn more about memory leak. I was set almost every object to null, after I didn't need to use it, but that didn't solve my problem. To import the data I'm using webservice with JSON between PHP and Android. When I try to import city by city, I'm getting a OutOfMemoryError after import some. Here is the LOG:

```
07-18 10:54:12.875: E/dalvikvm-heap(8420): Out of memory on a 16777232-byte allocation.
07-18 10:54:12.880: I/dalvikvm(8420): "AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=15 RUNNABLE
07-18 10:54:12.880: I/dalvikvm(8420):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42ad9168 self=0x597454d0
07-18 10:54:12.880: I/dalvikvm(8420):   | sysTid=8516 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1500748904
07-18 10:54:12.880: I/dalvikvm(8420):   | state=R schedstat=( 79546994965 27092848787 165998 ) utm=6340 stm=1614 core=3
07-18 10:54:12.890: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer.expand(CharArrayBuffer.java:~59)
07-18 10:54:12.890: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer.append(CharArrayBuffer.java:77)
07-18 10:54:12.895: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:136)
07-18 10:54:12.895: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
07-18 10:54:12.900: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at emater.gin.webservice.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:108)
07-18 10:54:12.905: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$DadosMunicipioWebservice.doInBackground(ModulosActivity.java:2499)
07-18 10:54:12.905: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$DadosMunicipioWebservice.doInBackground(ModulosActivity.java:1)
07-18 10:54:12.905: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 10:54:12.910: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 10:54:12.910: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-18 10:54:12.910: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 10:54:12.910: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 10:54:12.910: I/dalvikvm(8420):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-18 10:54:13.120: W/dalvikvm(8420): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e08700)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer.expand(CharArrayBuffer.java:59)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer.append(CharArrayBuffer.java:77)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:136)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at emater.gin.webservice.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:108)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$DadosMunicipioWebservice.doInBackground(ModulosActivity.java:2499)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$DadosMunicipioWebservice.doInBackground(ModulosActivity.java:1)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 10:54:13.125: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     ... 4 more
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420): Activity emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{451a8a50 V.E..... R....... 0,0-684,290} that was originally added here
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{451a8a50 V.E..... R....... 0,0-684,290} that was originally added here
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$DadosMunicipioWebservice.onPreExecute(ModulosActivity.java:2456)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at emater.gin.activities.ModulosActivity$5.onClick(ModulosActivity.java:328)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-18 10:54:22.915: E/WindowManager(8420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 10:54:29.695: I/Process(8420): Sending signal. PID: 8420 SIG: 9
```

The WindowLeak is happening because the activity is been closed, while there is a ProgressDialog open. The rest of the error I don't know why. Before happening this error, the dalvikvm is giving me in the log:

```
07-18 10:54:12.810: I/dalvikvm-heap(8420): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16777232-byte allocation
07-18 10:54:12.875: D/dalvikvm(8420): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 64% free 21345K/57992K, paused 65ms, total 65ms
```

I've tried to improve my code to not consume so much memory, that is the code where is happening the error.

This is my handler class, I use to make the call to the webservice:

PS: Forget the comments, it's portuguese, I'm from Brazil.

```
package emater.gin.webservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/*
 * Classe: ServiceHandler
 * Usada para leitura e envio de JSON.
 */
public class ServiceHandler 
{

    //Resposta
    static String response = null;

    //Recebe do servidor.
    public final static int GET = 1;

    //Envia para o servidor.
    public final static int POST = 2;

    //Construtor vazio.
    public ServiceHandler() {}

    //Faz a chamada para o servidor.
    public String makeServiceCall( String url, int method )
    {

        return this.makeServiceCall( url, method, null );

    }

    //Faz a chamada para o servidor.
    public String makeServiceCall( String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params )
    {

        try
        {

            //HTTP Client.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Entidade que pode ser enviada ou recebida.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            //Resposta HTTP.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            //Checa o tipo de request que vai ser feito.
            if( method == POST )
            {

                //Cria o HttpPost para enviar uma entidade.
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( url );

                //Adicona os parametros ao post.
                if( params != null )
                {

                    //Seta a entidade de respostas no httppost com os parametros passados.
                    httpPost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params ) );

                }

                //Pega a resposta do servidor a partida da enviada.
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPost );

            }else if( method == GET )
            {

                //Adiciona os parametros e gera a URL.
                if( params != null )
                {

                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format( params, "utf-8" );

                    url += "?" + paramString;

                }

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( url );

                //Envia a URL e pega a resposta.
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpGet );

            }

            //Liberar memoria.
            httpClient = null;

            //Pega a resposta e bota em uma nova entidade para ser usada.
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            //Liberar memoria.
            httpResponse = null;

            response = EntityUtils.toString( httpEntity );

        }catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch( ClientProtocolException e ) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch( IOException e )
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

And here is how I make this call to the server:

```
// Instancia para adicionar os parâmetros.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// Mostra o progesso aos poucos.
publishProgress(1);

// Adiciona os parametros a serem passados para o webservice.
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
            MunicipioUsuarioController.COLUMN_MUNICIPIO_ID, municipioId));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numeroserie", Secure.getString(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID)));

// Instancia quem vai lidar com o webservice.
ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();

// Faz um request a URL e pega a resposta.
String JSONString = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(
HTTP_URL_DADOS_MUNICIPIO, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
```

The error happens when I get the response from the webservice. But I don't think it's because the string is to big.
I really need help on that problem, if you could tell me some tips about memory leak too, it would be great. Help a poor trainee from brazil that as to develop a app all by himself.

Comment: How large is the file that causes this Out Of Memory Exception?

Comment: Well, I don't know how large is it, but is only text information. How it happers: I try to import a city with 4700 farmers, everything goes ok, I import a feel more city with 2000 farmers, and then when I try to import other with 4500 farmers the error comes.

Comment: Can you show us the `AsyncTask` or `Thread` or whatever you use to download the data? This would be the most likely candidate for a memory leak.

Comment: I use a AsyncTask, but is to big to show here. The beggining of my doInBackground method starts making the call to the servers, what part of it do you want to see?

Comment: Fix OoM exceptions is almost an artistic task, since every error use to be different to another. I advice you to use tools to analyze the heap usage. You can find [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html]) a brief explanation of how to use MAT. It worth to spend a time looking into this tool.